# Tool to wrap a process to allow multiple connections

Tags: networking, process, socat

Is there any tool that wraps a process (e.g. Bash) so that you can make "multiple" network connections to the "shared" process. Each connection can send input (e.g. setting environment variables, running external commands) to the process and will get corresponding output from the process.

The closest tool I found so far is using `socat`, like this:

```
server% socat exec:bash tcp-listen:1234,reuseaddr,fork

client1% socat - tcp:localhost:1234
client1% pwd
client1% x=123

client2% socat - tcp:localhost:1234
client2% echo $x   # print 123 (but on client1!)
```

But the problem is that when there are multiple active connections, the output (from the server) may not go to the client that sent the corresponding input.

Is there a workaround for this? Or is there another tool? And if possible, the tool should "serialize" input, so there would be no race condition.

My intention is to wrap a script that uses multiple libraries, so that instead of launching it every time (which take quite some time), I just make a connection to the running script process, and send a command to be run.

Comment: There's an excellent tutorial about the networking and coprocess features of gawk at http://home.vr-web.de/Juergen.Kahrs/gawk/gawkinet.html#Top , where you'd be rolling your own. Could do the same with perl too. The article references other tools (not socat), that may be of help. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and it disappeared after switching left and right address.

So you might try in your case:

```
socat tcp-listen:1234,reuseaddr,fork exec:bash
```

Comment: But you will get **seperate** `bash` shell for each connection: setting `x=123` on one connection, will not affect `echo $x` on another connection. What I want is a **shared** shell for all connections.